# Bug clip-path: url(svg) in Chrome if you use the CSS hover with Zoom (Ctrl+Wheel)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, clip-path

https://jsfiddle.net/wwb3ond0/

You can try to do rollover/hover with the zoom In or zoom Out. (Ctrl+Wheel)
In Firefox or Opera it works right, but not in Chrome.

It’s a bug or I am wrong?

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #a8d1ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#path);
    clip-path: url(#path);
}

div:hover
{
    background: #d343f2;
}


<!-- Bug hover in Chrome if you use the Zoom with Ctrl+Wheel -->
<!-- In Firefox works right -->
<div></div>

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <!-- Width: 100, Height: 100, PivotX: 50, PivotY: 50-->
        <clipPath id="path" transform='matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50)'>
            <path d='M 12.549999999999997 -12.799999999999997 L 0.04999999999999716 -50 L -12.5 -12.799999999999997 Q -31.25 -5.264257812499999 -50 -11.850000000000001 Q -39.544921875 2.703320312499997 -20.2 12.149999999999999 Q -13.455273437499997 35.24609375 -30.85 50 Q -4.446874999999999 40.41796875 2 19.200000000000003 Q 15.4013671875 29.63671875 30.900000000000006 50 Q 32.205468749999994 28.704492187499994 20.200000000000003 12.149999999999999 Q 31.088671875000003 -5.866992187500003 50 -11.850000000000001 Q 31.697851562500006 -18.498828125 12.549999999999997 -12.799999999999997'>
            </path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: and can you show the wrong output you get ?

Comment: This seems familiar..did you ask this before?

Comment: @foxfairlane If you think you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: 

Firefox result: https://ibb.co/eJ6C6m
Chrome  result: https://ibb.co/dciLsR

But is not only the visualization bug... if you try to do a rollover/hover with your mouse, in Firefox or Opera works ok, but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I never did ask it before because is my first post here, but I did post it in css-tricks.com too, maybe you saw it there.

Comment: @RobertLongson: I did it. I did report the bug to Chrome... but while they fix it. I am not 100% sure if I could get the expected result in another form...